# como passar duas structs por função

Tags: c, struct

Tenho duas structs,uma para os dados de alunos e outra para uma tabela hash,onde vão as colisões das matriculas.Para saber se houve colisão preciso dessas duas structs ,mas o dev diz que tem algum erro quando tento passar as duas para uma função.
essa função abaixo,esta dentro do inserir,o erro diz

> "expected expression before alunos" `tabela(alunos *al,thash *t);`

A função fica assim(não sei se vai funcionar pq nem consegui acessar ela pelo erro)

```
tabela(alunos *al,thash *t){
    alunos *p;
    thash *pp;
    int resto;

    for(p=al;p!=NULL;p=p->prox){

        resto=p->matri%4;
        pp->colisao[resto];
    }

}
```

Comment: Qual o tipo da função `tabela` ? Faltou essa parte. Pelo aspeto do código seria tipo `void`

Comment: Como você esta chamando a função `tabela()`?

Answer (score 0):

Se não houver um tipo definido para a `struct` é necessário informar de forma explicita a `struct`, basicamente assim `struct aluno a`. Além disso, a passagem da `struct` pode ser feita por referência ou por valor. Veja nos exemplos abaixo.

Passando uma `struct` para função por valor:

```
struct aluno lerAlunoValor(struct aluno a)
{
  printf("Digite o numero matricula (Por Valor): ");
  scanf("%i", &a.matricula);

  return a;
}
```

Passando uma `struct` para função por referência:

```
void lerAlunoRef(struct aluno *a)
{
  printf("Digite o numero matricula (Por referencia): ");
  scanf("%i", &a->matricula);
}
```

Repare que na passagem por valor é retornado uma nova `struct`, já na passagem por referência a `struct` é modificada dentro do escopo da função `lerAlunoRef()`.

Segue o exemplo completo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct aluno 
{
  int matricula;
};

struct aluno lerAlunoValor(struct aluno a)
{
  printf("Digite o numero matricula (Por Valor): ");
  scanf("%i", &a.matricula);

  return a;
}

void lerAlunoRef(struct aluno *a)
{
  printf("Digite o numero matricula (Por referencia): ");
  scanf("%i", &a->matricula);
}

int main(void) 
{
  struct aluno a, b;

  a = lerAlunoValor(a);

  lerAlunoRef(&b);

  printf("\n\nPor valor (Matricula): %i\n", a.matricula);
  printf("\n\nPor referencia (Matricula): %i\n", b.matricula);

  return 0;
}
```

Entrada:

> Digite o numero matricula (Por Valor): 122
>   Digite o numero matricula (Por referencia): 22

Saída:

> Por valor (Matricula): 122
>
> Por referencia (Matricula): 22

Veja funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/UglyCriminalScientists).

Pode consultar mais [aqui](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-structure-function).